# Чем управляет опция --align-payload в cryptosetup/LUKS?

Tags: linux, шифрование

Из man'а cryptosetup не совсем понятно. Нашел вот такой [мануал](https://web.archive.org/web/20200621204740/https://www.coolgeeks101.com/howto/infrastructure/full-disk-encryption-ubuntu-usb-detached-luks-header/) ,согласно ему эта опция управляет смещением криптоконтейнера/начала шифрованных данных в секторах от начала диска. Так все же, чем же управляет данная опция?

Answer (score 1):

Задаёт смещение криптоконтейнера в 512-байтных секторах от начала устройства. Если заголовок тут же - то смещение до заголовка. Если заголовок вынесен на отдельное устройство с помощью опции --header, то по указанному смещению будет находиться начало *данных* (то есть эта опция не будет относиться к заголовку, только к данным).

Comment: Примерно так я и думал,спасибо за подтверждение.